# Custom permalink question

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have a multisite environment where I am switching databases to retrieve data in a custom post type entered on one site to show on the other site.

On the site where the data is not stored (and the post type is not defined), I want a permalink like `/post-type-name/item-slug/` to end up at a page named `/post-type-name/`. I can then write code in the page specific template to switch databases, retrieve the data for item-slug, and show it. But I am not sure how to make the permalink work, other than to do it like `/post-type-name?item-slug`.

Comment: Ok, I looked around some more and was able to find a working solution here: https://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to [register your own Rewrite Rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). To do it you should use [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function.

```
function my_custom_external_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^post-type-name/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=<PAGE_ID>&external_page_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_external_rewrite_rule' );
```

And you'll have to register your custom query variable (using [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) hook):

```
function my_custom_external_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'external_page_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_external_query_var' );
```

This way requests to `post-type-name/slug/` will cause displaying page with  and you will be able to obtain the slug of external post with `get_query_var( 'external_page_name' );`

Comment: Thanks, the other solution I found omitted the step to register the query variable, so this was helpful. I had to change the $qvars variable to $query_vars in the code, otherwise all existing query variables were wiped out, which produced some interesting results...

Comment: @BarryTuber ha, nice catch ;) I was answering on mobile, so it was easy to overlook that typo. I've fixed that already.